# flutter_fortune_wheel spins on page load | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter_fortune_wheel: ^1.2.0 from pub.dev
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fortune_wheel
I have the Problem when i open the Page the wheel spins automatically. I want it to only spin when i Click it.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
      setState(() {
        selected.add(
          Random().nextInt(tricklist.length),
        );
      });
    },
    onVerticalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
      setState(() {
        selected.add(
          Random().nextInt(tricklist.length),
        );
      });
    },
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        selected.add(
          Random().nextInt(tricklist.length),
        );
      });
    },
    child: Stack(
      //fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: FortuneWheel(
              items: [
                for (var items in tricklist)
                  FortuneItem(
                    child: Text(items),
                  ),
              ],
              indicators: const <FortuneIndicator>[
                FortuneIndicator(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: TriangleIndicator(color: Colors.black)),
              ],
              selected: selected.stream,                                            
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make the animateFirst flag to false like so:

```
animateFirst: false
```

and use the *onFling* callback to add the behavior you want when the touches the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using any third-party packages as much as you can as they may not be maintained properly and can use the core Flutter animation functions provided by it. As Flutter animations are very simple and easy to use. For your use case, we can easily spin any widget using a double tween and animation controller on Transform.rotate() method.

Check this for more info : [Create wheel of fortune animation in flutter](https://blog.toptime.club/home/flutter/how-to-make-a-wheel-of-fortune/how-to-make-a-wheel-of-fortune.html)

Comment: any affiliation with the blog? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).